# Why is my character model constantly shrinking?

Tags: fallout-4

So, I have this curious problem with my character model. The problem being that my character models shrink when I exit V.A.T.S or enter a new area. The commands `player.setscale` and `player.modscale` are only temporary, as they are just hotfixes. As soon as one of the former mentioned criteria are met, my character model just reverts back to its "original" size (Which I suspect is 0.80 in height). Does anybody perhaps have a way of making either console commands permanent?

Comment: Do you have any mods installed?

Comment: My original post has been updated with the relevant information. Can't believe i forgot it the first time.

Comment: As usual: disable all mods.  Does the problem go away?  Then it's one of them.  Which one it is, is left as an exercise to the asker.

Comment: Wait, so the problem is just that setscale is temporary, and you want it to be permanent?

Comment: Mod: [Change Player Height (shorter)](http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/13331/?tab=4&&navtag=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nexusmods.com%2Ffallout4%2Fajax%2Fcomments%2F%3Fmod_id%3D13331%26page%3D2%26sort%3DDESC%26pid%3D0%26thread_id%3D4107835&pUp=1). Looks like you also have to edit "the player and the playerjj01 files in the actors in the ck"